# Compare 2 arrays for likeness

Tags: php, arrays, compare

How would I compare 2 Arrays in PHP to find which values each array have in common.

Example would be

**Array 1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ace
    [1] => one
    [2] => five
    [3] => nine
    [4] => elephant
)
```

**Array 2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => elephant
    [1] => seven
    [2] => ace
    [3] => jack
    [4] => queen
)
```

**Output**
Array
(
    [0] => ace
    [1] => elephant
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function can do this.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has an [array_intersect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function that can do this. As an example, ypo can put the following code into [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) for testing:

```
<?php
    $array1 = array('ace', 'one', 'five', 'nine', 'elephant');
    $array2 = array('elephant', 'seven', 'ace', 'jack', 'queen');

    print_r($array1); print('<br>');
    print_r($array2); print('<br>');
    print_r(array_intersect($array1, $array2)); print('<br>');
?>
```

Then you'll see that it gives you what you want (reformatted for readability):

```
Array ( [0] => ace
        [1] => one
        [2] => five
        [3] => nine
        [4] => elephant )

Array ( [0] => elephant
        [1] => seven
        [2] => ace
        [3] => jack
        [4] => queen )

Array ( [0] => ace
        [4] => elephant )
```

Do note that this does not actually give you *consecutive* keys in the result, the keys appear to come from the first array given to `array_intersect()`. If it's important that you get a consecutively-indexed array, you may need a post-processing step to adjust it. Something like this should be a good start (modification to original fiddle to use consecutive indexes):

```
<?php
    $array1 = array('ace', 'one', 'five', 'nine', 'elephant');
    $array2 = array('elephant', 'seven', 'ace', 'jack', 'queen');

    print_r($array1); print('<br>');
    print_r($array2); print('<br>');

    $array3 = array();
    foreach (array_intersect($array1, $array2) as $val) {
        array_push($array3, $val);
    }
    print_r($array3); print('<br>');
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're in a language where there is no built-in intersection, but you have hashes, you just add all the elements of one array into the hash and then go through the second array checking to see if they are in the hash you just built up.

This is all of if you don't care about order.  If you care about order, it's just a for loop seeing if a[i] == b[i]