# Compare dynamic arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I would like help finishing my function that compares two arrays and returns the values of the element that are the same in both.

```
$array1 = array("bob","mike","david","gary");
$array2 = array("susan","jenny","mike");
```

The two arrays will have different amounts of elements every time. I run the function below and it says there are matches but wont tell me which ones. Also will my function work if the array does not have the same amount of elements?

```
echo  find_matches($array1,$array2);


function find_matches($mac1, $mac2){

   $matches = array();

   foreach($mac1 as $mac){
         if(in_array($mac, $mac2)){
            $matches[] = $mac;
         }
   }

    if ($matches != 0){

    $error_message = "The following numbers match: " . implode(' ', $matches);

    return $error_message;
    }else{
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you wanna say "if (count($matches)>0){" toward the end?  My PHP is rusty.  Other than that, I think your logic should properly compare different sized arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare 2 arrays for likeness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065431/compare-2-arrays-for-likeness)

Comment: You believe you are corrent about using count() before comparing. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're looking to return the number of matches and the matches themselves, you could use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
$matches = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: Well there's 2 hours I will never get back. Thanks.